# Assertion failed: native function `int_sqrt` called before runtime initialization error while calling c function in .js file ( emscripten )

Tags: emscripten, asm.js

I am not able to call a C function in another JavaScript file, it is giving the error  'called before runtime initialization'  [please refer to this link](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-ccall-cwrap.)

I compiled the C code in emscripten as described in the given link and used generated asm.js file in my test.js file.
command used to generate asm :-

```
emcc test/hello.cpp -o hello.html -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_int_sqrt']" -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS="["ccall", "cwrap"]"
```

code in test.js file :

```
var Module = require('./asm.js');
var test =  Module.cwrap('int_sqrt', 'number', ['number']);
console.log(test(25));
```

and when I run `node test` it gives the error

> ```
> abort(Assertion failed: native function `int_sqrt` called before runtime initialization)
> ```

Answer (score 7):

you should wait for runtime init.
try this:

```
var Module = require("./lib.js");
var result = Module.onRuntimeInitialized = () => {
    Module.ccall('myFunction', // name of C function 
        null, // return type
        null, // argument types
        null // arguments
   );
}
```

Comment: eventually, I got the answer and I guess if we add WASM = 0 flag while compiling then we might not wait for runtime init. And thankyou so much for your answer sir.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while using **emscripten** and this has worked for me:

```
<script>
    Module.onRuntimeInitialized = () => { Module.functionName(param); }
</script>
```

Where **functionName** is the name of the function that you want to invoke and **param** is the value that you want to pass to it.